Facing an issue in hitting the amazon selling partner api
Error Details:
Endpoint: POST https://sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/shipping/v2/shipments/rates
Error Message:
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "code":"Unauthorized",
         "message":"Access to requested resource is denied.",
         "details":""
      }
   ]
}

Request Details:
Headers:

x-amz-access-token: Atza|IwEBIMaflN68hEHq
x-amzn-shipping-business-id: AmazonShipping_IN

Request Body:
{
    "shipTo": {
        "name": "Pavan",
        "addressLine1": "Shop No 4",
        "addressLine2": "Sec No 11",
        "postalCode": "500032",
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "countryCode": "IN",
        "email": "gunjikah+in12@amazon.com",
        "phoneNumber": "9999999999"
    },
    "shipFrom": {
        "name": "A1",
        "addressLine1": "1141,Maker Chambers V",
        "addressLine2": "J Bajaj Road, Nariman Point",
        "postalCode": "500032",
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "countryCode": "IN",
        "email": "cct-prod-test@amazon.com",
        "phoneNumber": "9999999999"
    },
    "packages": [
        {
            "dimensions": {
                "length": 3.14,
                "width": 3.14,
                "height": 3.14,
                "unit": "INCH"
            },
            "weight": {
                "unit": "KILOGRAM",
                "value": 3.14159
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "weight": {
                        "unit": "KILOGRAM",
                        "value": 1.14159
                    },
                    "isHazmat": false
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "weight": {
                        "unit": "KILOGRAM",
                        "value": 1.14159
                    }
                }
            ],
            "insuredValue": {
                "unit": "INR",
                "value": 29.98
            },
            "isHazmat": false,
            "packageClientReferenceId": "abcd"
        }
    ],
    "valueAddedServices": {
        "collectOnDelivery": {
            "amount": {
                "value": 10,
                "unit": "INR"
            }
        }
    },
    "taxDetails": [
        {
            "taxType": "GST",
            "taxRegistrationNumber": "87878"
        }
    ],
    "channelDetails": {
        "channelType": "EXTERNAL"
    }
}

Testing in Postman

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the x-amz-access-token is correct and not expired.
Ensured the x-amzn-shipping-business-id is accurate.
Double-checked the endpoint URL and headers.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists.

Please, check that your application on Seller Central has the Direct-to-Consumer Shipping role and, if the request of that role has been sent, that it has been approved, the case is closed and the application is out of the Draft mode.

Thanks for your response... Will check it
